# remote query against mysql server takes much more time (40s vs 1.8s)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-performance

** check update 5 at the bottom ** - looks like a bug of mysql connectors.
Thanks all the helpers for improving my original table :-) but the issue goes deeper than that.

I have a simple query that takes 1.8s on the server, but 40s from remote connection.
the query returns 1 row:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE cola <= 123456789012345 and 123456789012345 <= colb
```

server is mysql 8.0.21.
this query running in workbench takes 1.89s

same query running on my own computer in navicat client takes anything between 30s and 60s based on server load.

the query returns one row from a 10M rows table.

what might cause the difference (Internet connection is fiber, and fast) ?
anyway to solve this ?

Explain results:

** UPDATE **

same query has difference in execution time on slow log when coming locally or remotely as described.
same query running against mariadb on linux server remotly shows good performance (2s) both local and remotely.

something is off with the mysql 8.0.21 on windows I guess. maybe an upgrade process caused this ?

Explain results:

```
Select type: Simple 
Type: ALL 
Possible keys: cola, colb cola-colb,colb-cola 
key: null 
key_lenn: null 
rows: 10M 
filtered: 22.58 
Extra:
using WHERE.
```

** UPDATE 2 - Show Create Table (same on local and remote) **

```
CREATE TABLE `d` (
   `cola` decimal(39,0) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `colb` decimal(39,0) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `a` char(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
   `b` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
   `c` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
   `d` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `idx_cola` (`cola`),
   KEY `idx_colb` (`colb`),
   KEY `idx_cola_colb` (`cola`,`colb`),
   KEY `idx_colb_cola` (`colb`,`cola`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

** UPDATE 3 **
After the comments about myISAM I've converted the table to INNODB.
it had 2 effects:
A. processing time now is almost equal for remote and local
B. they are both 6-7s and not the 2s it used to be as MyISAM.
C. Horrible - after fixing the indexes as as @Rick James suggested I've got the server running the query in less than 1s but remote stayed 7s

so on one hand I'm happy I'm down from 40s to 7s, but how come the performance got so worst from local to remote ?

** UPDATE 4 **

I have built a small app to run the query and installed it on the server
my app using localhost as server address takes 7s to run the query.
Workbench on the same query - 0.9s.
Tried Work Bench From Remote address and it keeps the 0.9s
Navicat / mysql.data connector for mysql 8.0.21 -  from remote address - 7s !
I can't understand why is the difference.

** UPDATE 5 **
reproduced on my own computer. Workbench 0.9. code and navicat 7s.
opened a bug at bugs.mysql.com

** UPDATE 6 **

performance schema:
[image]

The exact same query just from workbench:

[image]

Comment: What if you ask for it IMMEDIATELY AGAIN after the first remote connection of 40s? Will it still take 40s?

Comment: @ZioBit yes. 40s again and again.

Comment: Test the variant: create SP with this query, call it remotely. Does the time will be ~1.8s?

Comment: I guess you know more than me but in case you didn't think of something... Can you run - both remotely and otherwise - an EXPLAIN SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE cola <= 123456789012345 and 123456789012345 <= colb ... to see if there is any difference, to see what kind of indexes - if any - is using, and so on...

Comment: @ZioBit explain shows same results both local and remote. slow log shows exact same resutls local and remote but remote shows the 40s and local 1.8 (some amount of rows count and fetch)

Comment: @Akina that's a solution - but it solve the symptom - not the problem. I want/need to understand why this query takes so much time remotely.

Comment: Let's analyze the "remotely" part then. Is it using the standard 3306 port? Or with some sort of SSL? Then maybe remotely there is a problem with a certificate, or some checks wait for too long, or some things must wait for a timeout... Remotely HOW?

Comment: since the slow-log shows the actual running time of the query (40s in remote,2 local) it can't be all the things you've mentioned. @ZioBit, but I can try and check, there is no certificate I believe, regular 3306 connection.

Comment: *it solve the symptom - not the problem* Of course - this was a test, not a solution. Please find the way to get detailed profile of this query execution - what step of total execution (local server caching, network transfer, local client parsing) takes this extreme time.

Comment: Then I think it's a standard debug thing... Remove one variable at a time, and see if it makes a difference. Are you able to upload THE SAME DB to a TOTALLY DIFFERENT SERVER and run the same query?

Comment: yep - another server - remote query. 2s. @ZioBit - nice input. (2nd server was maria on linux, this is mysql on windows...)

Comment: `EXPLAIN {query}` on both.

Comment: Yes, on both.  Especially if using 8.0 versus MariaDB.  Ditto for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  8.0 is likely to changed it to `InnoDB` !

Comment: looks like a bug in mysql. retesting now on my local computer.

Comment: Please add links to the bug reports.  I would like to see what they say.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/100812

Comment: @RickJames Just figured this out - Workbench sends the query to the server with limit 0,1000. my code and navicat (although also set to show only 1000 rows) doesn't adds this to the query. that's made the whole difference between 1.5s query to 14s query. MariaDB doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @Dani - That `LIMIT` controls the amount of data sent 'across the wire'.  But it _may_ or _may not_ avoid the server having to fetch all the relevant rows before chopping to 1000.  That depends on the query and the indexes.  Meanwhile there are a small number of optimization strategies that differ between MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: @Dani - "Internet connection is fiber" -- "fiber" provides capacity, not speed.  "Speed" is limited by the speed of light (or a least a significant fraction).  If the server is on the other side of the globe, it takes over 200ms, regardless of "fiber".

Comment: @RickJames I aware, but the test showed same results on a local server so rule out the internet factor. And since the query returns 1 row as a result, it's not a factor in my opinion to the huge difference between running the same query with or without a limit. the only reason I "know" it - b/c mariadb overcame this and gives fast results without the limit 0,1000 clause.

Comment: @Dani - OK, good.  Can you get `EXPLAIN SELECT` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT`  from both machines and add them to your Question.  (So far, you have 1 of those 4.)

Comment: explain was the same - but what I've missed was that workbench was adding limit 0,1000 to the query - which made it work super fast (this does not occure in maria) I'll upload the table to my  mysql  bug report - so they can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for this issue.
It looks like WORKBENCH is adding to the query sent to the server limit 0,1000 at the end.
Although the query only returns 1 row, it makes a 10s difference in execution time - with and without that addition.

MariaDB seems to be immune to this, as the query works the same with and without this addition.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend these two 2-column indexes:

```
INDEX(cola, colb)
INDEX(colb, cola)
```

Do *not* also have `INDEX(cola)` and `INDEX(colb)`; the optimizer will erroneously prefer to use them.

I assume that the two columns and the constants are timestamps?  And you are checking for overlap?  Is the particular query searching near one "end" of the timestamps?

How much RAM do you have?  How big (in GB) is the table?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Do *not* use MyISAM.  It is old, removed from 8.0, has fewer optimizations, etc.

`decimal(39,0)` -- Really?  What kind of value are these?  That takes 18 bytes.

If you are pointing out an optimization difference between 8.0 and MariaDB, make it clearer that that is the point.  Workbench is just a UI; it has nothing to do with the processing *except* that it might deliver the first few rows "quickly", thereby fooling you into thinking that it is faster.

When switching from MyISAM to InnoDB, you must adjust `key_buffer_size` (lower) and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (much higher).  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

Comment: both indexes exists. they are not being used. I'll add explain to the main Q.

Comment: @Dani Please POST EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your query) ...... results from both LOCAL and REMOTE with time to completion. A) Actual queries from each system, B) OS and version and MySQL version? C) TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE d; from each system.

Comment: Explain Select sql_no_cache is same as posted above for both remote and local. (both returned immediately)

Comment: OS: windows 2016 server, mysql 8.0.21

Comment: show create similar from both local and remote - added t the original quesion.

Comment: @Dani - I added lots to my Answer.

Comment: I don't think this is a mysql-maria db issue. the difference between  them is not so big. since the issue is remove vs. localhost I checked remote on another db I have (happens to be maria and it is innodb)

Comment: MYISAM was not intended but altering it to INNODB did 2 things: query time of remote and local became the same. BUT - now it's 7 seconds both remote and on the server.  I can't understand this.

Comment: @Dani Have you considered changing the query into  SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE cola <= 123456789012345 and colb <= 123456789012345;  ? If you would be kind enough to post current TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE d; we would be able to see what you have at this time.

Comment: @Dani - Did you also adjust `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  I added to my Answer; it seems that the buffer_pool_size is the problem.

Comment: I'm made more tests - looks like the real diff is the "client" - workbench - remote and local gets me the results in 0.9s, any other client - like my code or navicat - 7s !

Comment: @Dani You may want to consider using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html  to dig deeper than SET PROFILING=1; which is still available to determine detailed resource utilization in picoseconds to identify what is using 7s.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the results to the Q. all the time were spent in stage/sql/executing

Comment: Since the execute time is so extremely different - more than 6 seconds to 0.nnnnn seconds.
Please post TEXT results from each EXPLAIN SELECT ...; Thanks

Comment: @Dani - And run each test twice -- to avoid caching confusing the timings.  7s vs 0.9s could very well indicate just an I/O caching difference. (cf Update 4)

Comment: I've run them 100 times... :-) same results.